# Java Spoonerizer Method

Tags: java

I'm working on a lab where I need to create an algorithm to "spoonerize" a string. This is an example of a spoonerized sentence:

Initial input: "you have missed the history lectures”
Spoonerization: "you have hissed the mistory lectures"

In particular, I need to:

1. Split the input sentence into an array of strings where each array element
   contains a word.
2. Generate a random index i of the array, where i is less than the array length - 1. Use the call new Random().nextInt(bound) to gen- erate a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and bound (exclusive).
3. Swap the first character of the array element at index i and i + 1. You will find charAt and substring methods of the String class useful. In particular, you should use charAt to retrieve the first character of a word and use substring to retrieve the rest of the word. After switching the first characters of the two consecutive words, you write them back to their original array position.
4. Concatenate the array elements to form a new string and return it.
   You can join a string array back into a single string with a loop and
   an accumulator variable. Alternatively, you can use the static method String.join(separator, stringArray),whichconcatenatesthestringArray argument into a single string separated by the separator.

This is what I have:

```
    package lab2;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    PrintStream out = System.out;

    out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    out.println("Spoonerized = ");
    out.println(spoonerize(s));

    in.close();
}

private static String spoonerize(String s) { 
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");    
    int random = new Random().nextInt(arr.length - 1);
    char firstLetterFirstWord = (arr[random].charAt(0));
    String restOfWord = arr[random].substring(1, ???);



    return null;
```

}
}

I can't seem to figure out how to use the substring method to get the rest of the word, and what to do from there. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: There's a single parameter version of `substring()` too you know. Check out the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use either :

```
arr[random].substring(1, arr[random].length())
```

or easier :

```
arr[random].substring(1);
```

For the concatenation, use either `+` or use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("This ");
sb.append("is ");
sb.append("an ");
sb.append("example");

String result = sb.toString();
```